# Difference between values in Column by group

Tags: r, dplyr

Hi I need to achieve something like this :

```
grp value   diff
1   10       NA  # diff[1] = value[2]-value[0] of grp = 1
1   15       10  # diff[2] = value[3]-value[1] of grp = 1
1   20       -5  # diff[3] = value[4]-value[2] of grp = 1
1   10       NA  # diff[4] = value[5]-value[3] of grp = 1
2   25       NA  # diff[5] = value[6]-value[4] of grp = 2
2   30       10  # diff[6] = value[7]-value[5] of grp = 2
2   35       NA  # diff[7] = value[8]-value[6] of grp = 2
```

I have tried using functions like `shift` and `lag` but cannot get this type of solution where I take the difference of preceding values and subtract them, where it is as `diff[i] = value[i+1] - value[i-1]`

Using `for loop` is running into errors, so is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Also, `# diff[3] = value[4]-value[3] of grp = 1`, I think you are looking for `# diff[3] = value[4]-value[2] of grp = 1`, am I right ?

Comment: @akrun yes sorry for the little typo, it's `diff[3] = value[4]-value[2]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have a typo in the description of your differential values.
However, if you want that `diff[i]` to be the `value[i+1]` - `value[i-1]`, you can do it by using both `lead` and `lag` in `dplyr`

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(grp) %>% mutate(diff = lead(value) -lag(value))

# A tibble: 7 x 3
# Groups:   grp [2]
    grp value  diff
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1    10    NA
2     1    15    10
3     1    20    -5
4     1    10    NA
5     2    25    NA
6     2    30    10
7     2    35    NA
```

**EDIT: Absolute difference**

If you need the absolute difference, you can do:

```r
df %>% group_by(grp) %>% mutate(diff = abs(lead(value) -lag(value)))

# A tibble: 7 x 3
# Groups:   grp [2]
    grp value  diff
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1    10    NA
2     1    15    10
3     1    20     5
4     1    10    NA
5     2    25    NA
6     2    30    10
7     2    35    NA
```

Does it look what you are looking for ?

**Data**

```r
df = data.frame(grp = c(rep(1,4),rep(2,3)),
                value = c(10,15,20,10,25,30,35))
```

Comment: You're welcome ! But are you looking for having `5` or `-5` on the third row ? You did not mention in your question the need of absolute difference but if it is `5` you are looking for, the solution of @akrun using `abs` is more appropriate.

Comment: Yes, thank you for explaining about the `abs`, I get it now.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused, are you looking for the absolute difference ? or the difference ? I edited my answer to provide both answers but if you are looking for absolute difference, you should validate @akrun's answer as he posted it first.

Comment: I am actually not looking for abs value but I found your answer very simple and easy to understand with just once glance and hence, I just validated yours. They both work and solve the problem, I wish I could accept them both @dc37

Answer (score 2):

After grouping by 'grp', we can get the difference of `lead` with 'value' and take the `lag` of it

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  group_by(grp)
  mutate(diff = lag(abs(lead(value, 2) - value)))
# A tibble: 7 x 3
# Groups:   grp [2]
#    grp value  diff
#  <int> <int> <int>
#1     1    10    NA
#2     1    15    10
#3     1    20     5
#4     1    10    NA
#5     2    25    NA
#6     2    30    10
#7     2    35    NA
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(grp = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), value = c(10L, 
15L, 20L, 10L, 25L, 30L, 35L)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Hi @akrun, this gives me an error like this `Error in mutate_(.data, .dots = compat_as_lazy_dots(...)) : argument ".data" is missing, with no default`

Comment: @KrushikaTapedia  I used  your dataset, not getting error for me

Comment: @KrushikaTapedia  Not clear about the error as I can't reproduce it any way after posting first and the indexing was not correct in your example post